# Uncaught TypeError: navigator.getBattery is not a function

Tags: javascript, battery

I'm developping a website which is meant to be used on mobile devices using Google Chrome, the purpose is to list information such as time (hh:mm) and battery level.
I saw the Battery Web API but I'm experiencing a strange error:
[click to see the chrome error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhFwm.png)

Here is the code I used in order to get the battery level:

```
navigator.getBattery().then(function (battery) {
    console.log(Math.round(battery.level * 100))
});
```

I had the error yesterday, without changing any line of code, it is working today on my tablet (chrome version: 103), but I tested on another tablet (Samsung Galaxy TAB A7 LITE, Chrome version: 103) and I encounter the error, I restarted several times the devices, inspected pages using the devtools connected by cable to my laptop, but I can't solve this error.

I saw a topic having the same error but he was developing a web worker it is not the same context as I.

No matter when I'm calling the `navigator.getBattery()` if the error appeared in the beginning it will stay undefined later, so it is not a problem of timing to call it (I even bound it to the `body.onload` but it didn't work).

I thought it could be authorization issues on system information but there's nothing refering to the battery which is not authorized in the application settings of Chrome.

Any help is welcome :D

Comment: According to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_navigator_getbattery) you need atleast a Chrome version of 104 on Android to have `navigator.getBattery` available.

Comment: @Palladium02 following https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Battery_Status_API it is fully supported since Chrome version 38 on Android devices. I also tested on a Google Pixel 6 using Chrome version 104 and it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I found out where my error was coming from.
It is a problem of HTTPS, my testing environment is configured behind a NGINX HTTP Server, which serves HTTP and HTTPS version of my application in order to use a single certificate for every of my projects, Chrome on my laptop prefix URLs I'm accessing with `https://` and it is hidden in the navbar, but it is not the case on Chrome tablet or mobile, I thought I was consulting the HTTPS version but it was HTTP, and Battery Web API isn't accessible on HTTP websites, it is required to have a secure connection using HTTPS and certificates. It has nothing to do with version number since Battery Web API is fully supported since Chrome version 38 according to MDN Documentation.